# Can I manually edit the points along a path or curve in the blender UI?

Tags: bezier-curves, edit-mode

I create a curve or a path in Blender and can clearly see that it is defined by a set of points. What I want to do is manually edit the position of one of these points, instead of dragging it. That way I can ensure my curve / path is 100% accurate in terms of direction and length.

I am new to Blender and this community, so forgive me if this question is stupid. I have searched google, this site, and the blender manuals and have found nothing.

How can I do this in the Blender UI?

My properties menu looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Since you accepted my answer, I assume you already found the right place, but I added an image that shows the entire properties panel anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit mode, press <kbd>N</kbd> or click *View -> Properties* to open the properties panel. Then, under *Transform* you will have *Control Point*. This is the coordinates of the currently selected point. If you have several points selected, it will change to *Median* and editing the values, will move all selected points so that their median is located at the specified coordinates.

[image]

By Properties panel, I'm refering to the area that I marked with red edges in the image below. If it's not visible, you need to open it, either by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> or by clicking *View -> Properties*

[image]

Comment: @nhouser9 You're welcome. A side note. If you use NURBS instead of Bezier, you also have a **w** parameter. That is a weight, that further controls the shape, and it's not related to the **w** of quaternion rotations. I've not done much NURBS though, and I have never bothered to learn the math behind them, so I can't explain closer than that.